# Laravel 5.1 : Queue event in background not working

Tags: laravel, events, queue, amazon-sqs, laravel-5.1

I have created a test event under \app\Events\TestEventTriggered.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Events\Event;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class TestEventTriggered extends Event
{
    use SerializesModels;


    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {        }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should be broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

And an event listener under app\Listeners\ListenToMyEvent.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners\Events;

use App\Events\TestEventTriggered;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeQueued;

class ListenToMyEvent implements ShouldBeQueued
{
    use InteractsWithQueue;

    /**
     * Create the event handler.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  TestEventTriggered  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(TestEventTriggered $event)
    {
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

In app\Providers\EventServiceProvider.php :

```
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\TestEventTriggered' => [
        'App\Listeners\ListenToMyEvent'
    ]
];
```

I then trigger the event for example inside my model's save method :

```
\Event::fire(new \App\Events\TestEventTriggered);
```

When i save my model now the event is processed synchronously. So the event's handle method is not processed by the queue.

The docs say to implement the ShouldBeQueued contract in the listener, which is the case in my listener. However, how am i supposed to actually push the event's handle method to the queue? What steps am i missing here? Where do i declare to which queue/tube the event should be pushed?
I am using Amazon SQS to handle my queues.

The laravel docs are a bit confusing about this matter...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think the docs is pretty straightforwad, http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#pushing-jobs-onto-the-queue. You need to have a background process running to listen to the queue:`php artisan queue:listen`

Comment: yeah the listener is running, but the problem is i can't set the queue. I have several queues and so it just takes the default queue in the queue config file

Comment: according to the docs, you can use onQueue('queue_name') to specify which you want to dispatch the job to. `$job = (new SendReminderEmail($user))->onQueue('emails'); $this->dispatch($job);`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add a queue method in which you can set the specific tube the event should be sent to :

```
public function queue($queue, $command)
{
    $queue->pushOn('your_queue_name',$command);
}
```

Comment: Lol, thanks, I can't believe how tough this one was to come up with! I was close to dispatch it just myself within the listener, but that seemed not fully "L-ish". Thanks again.